# Post Request to CoinFloor API in Excel VBA not working - Getting 415 Unsupported Media Type Error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to access CoinFloor BIST API through Excel VBA or Access VBA. I am able to make get requests (like ticker) successfully. But when I try a post request (like get balance) I get an error "415 Unsupported Media Type". I looked through many threads for this error and all are pointing to the content-type and accept headers, but I was not able to get it working.

The code is pasted below.

```
Function BalancePostRequest()

Dim auth, URL, data
Dim cred As Credentials
Dim Lib As New jsonlib

cred = getCredentials

auth = cred.userId & "/" & cred.API_Key & ":" & cred.passphrase

URL = "https://webapi.coinfloor.co.uk:8090/bist/XBT/GBP/balance/"

Dim xhr: Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With xhr
    .Open "POST", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json" 
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(auth)
End With

xhr.send data

If xhr.Status <> 200 Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1000, "Util.SendRequest", "Status code: " & xhr.Status & " " & xhr.statusText & ". Response was: " & xhr.responseText
End If

Set xhr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: It would help if you stated the line on which it errors.

Comment: xhr.send data throws the error

Comment: And what is data?

Comment: Also, here is the link to the API documentation, if that helps --https://github.com/coinfloor/API/blob/master/BIST.md

Comment: as there are no post parameters required in this, data is blank